# webserver with specified root folder via gulp task

Tags: npm, gulp

I've take a look at a few gulp server instances (currently using gulp-webserver) but I can't seem to find where to set the root folder for the server [per the params I see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver)  See code below:

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src(debugFolder)
    .pipe(webserver({
      directoryListing: true
    }));
});
```

I'm not sure what the gulp.src param does as it's not the root.  The root is the folder that holds the gulp script.  Am I missing something on this module or is there another module that will do this?  Trying to keep things clean and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use `gulp-webserver` for it, since it's not a Gulp plugin and has been [blacklisted](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json) by the community. I'd suggest you to use [BrowserSync](http://browsersync.io), which does exactly what you need and is a lot more standalone. Check out [this documentation](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/) or my little [writeup here](http://fettblog.eu/php-browsersync-grunt-gulp/). It would work like this:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./app/"
        }
    });
});
```

And it's able to do a lot more!